# Flutter custom shape using CustomPaint

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I just want my created shape so that i can stack a widget to achieve the Image below. i am trying to get the transparent shape at the back ground of the X and Love. I Try using the shape maker but my mouse designing is not perfect. here is the code generated from the shape maker

```
    child: CustomPaint(
      size: Size(400,(400*0.2857142857142857).toDouble()),
      painter: RPSCustomPainter(),
    ),

class RPSCustomPainter extends CustomPainter{
  
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    
    

  Paint paint_0 = new Paint()
      ..color = Color.fromARGB(255, 33, 150, 243)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 1;
     
         
        Path path_0 = Path();
        path_0.moveTo(size.width*0.2137714,size.height*0.2524000);
        path_0.cubicTo(size.width*0.1736143,size.height*0.4775500,size.width*0.1973000,size.height*0.6711500,size.width*0.2153286,size.height*0.7510000);
        path_0.cubicTo(size.width*0.2270429,size.height*0.7777500,size.width*0.2705286,size.height*0.9439500,size.width*0.3556000,size.height*0.7521500);
        path_0.cubicTo(size.width*0.3856000,size.height*0.6504000,size.width*0.3970143,size.height*0.6162000,size.width*0.4283571,size.height*0.7526000);
        path_0.cubicTo(size.width*0.4669286,size.height*0.8264000,size.width*0.5172429,size.height*0.9022500,size.width*0.5719714,size.height*0.7500000);
        path_0.cubicTo(size.width*0.6146429,size.height*0.5440500,size.width*0.5914429,size.height*0.3101000,size.width*0.5713714,size.height*0.2514000);
        path_0.cubicTo(size.width*0.5520714,size.height*0.1778000,size.width*0.4875429,size.height*0.0767500,size.width*0.4296571,size.height*0.2527000);
        path_0.cubicTo(size.width*0.4023714,size.height*0.3646000,size.width*0.3816857,size.height*0.3850000,size.width*0.3557143,size.height*0.2523000);
        path_0.cubicTo(size.width*0.3438571,size.height*0.2086000,size.width*0.2652143,size.height*0.0579000,size.width*0.2137714,size.height*0.2524000);
        path_0.close();
    
        canvas.drawPath(path_0, paint_0);
      
        
      }
    
      @override
      bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
        return true;
      }
      
    }
```

what i am trying to achieve

[image]

my result. the shape is not perfect.

thanks

[image: result image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I wanted to describe you the ways you can achieve the shape you want and so on...

But got carried away with this fun programming challenge and ended up creating an actual widget :)

It depends on the **font_awesome_flutter** package, so don't forget to install it (for the heart icon). [font_awesome_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter)

So the widget's source code is:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

extension ToRadians on int {
  double get toRadians => this * (math.pi / 180.0);
}

enum _ButtonType { like, dislike }

class LikeOrNot extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onLike;
  final VoidCallback onDislike;

  // Percents from total widget width, default - 2%
  final _gapSizeRatio = 0.02;

  final _likeIconColor = const Color(0xffb85076);
  final _dislikeIconColor = Colors.white;

  const LikeOrNot({
    Key? key,
    required this.onLike,
    required this.onDislike,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 2,
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          final buttonPaddings = constraints.maxHeight * 0.1;
          final halfWidth = constraints.maxWidth / 2;
          return Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned.fill(
                child: CustomPaint(
                  painter: RPSCustomPainter(
                    gapSizeRatio: _gapSizeRatio,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                top: 0,
                right: halfWidth + constraints.maxWidth * _gapSizeRatio,
                child: SizedBox.expand(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(buttonPaddings),
                    child: _buildButton(_ButtonType.dislike),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                right: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                top: 0,
                left: halfWidth + constraints.maxWidth * _gapSizeRatio,
                child: SizedBox.expand(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(buttonPaddings),
                    child: _buildButton(_ButtonType.like),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildButton(_ButtonType buttonType) {
    final isPositiveAction = buttonType == _ButtonType.like;

    return ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        shape: const CircleBorder(),
        primary: isPositiveAction ? _dislikeIconColor : _likeIconColor,
        onPrimary: isPositiveAction ? _likeIconColor : _dislikeIconColor,
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        elevation: 10,
        shadowColor: Colors.black54,
      ),
      onPressed: onDislike,
      child: FractionallySizedBox(
        widthFactor: 0.35,
        heightFactor: 0.35,
        child: FittedBox(
          child: isPositiveAction
              ? const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.heart)
              : const Icon(Icons.close),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RPSCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final double gapSizeRatio;

  RPSCustomPainter({
    required this.gapSizeRatio,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black.withOpacity(0.08)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = 1;

    final path = Path();

    final gapSize = size.width * gapSizeRatio;
    final arcRadius = size.height / 2 - gapSize / 2;

    final leftCircleCenter = Offset(
      size.width * 0.25 - gapSize / 2,
      size.height / 2,
    );
    final rightCircleCenter = Offset(
      size.width * 0.75 + gapSize / 2,
      size.height / 2,
    );

    path.arcTo(
      Rect.fromCircle(
        center: leftCircleCenter,
        radius: arcRadius,
      ),
      45.toRadians,
      270.toRadians,
      false,
    );

    final bezierOffset = arcRadius * (105 / 360);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      size.width / 2,
      size.height * 0.30,
      rightCircleCenter.dx - arcRadius + bezierOffset,
      rightCircleCenter.dy - arcRadius + bezierOffset,
    );

    path.arcTo(
      Rect.fromCircle(
        center: rightCircleCenter,
        radius: arcRadius,
      ),
      225.toRadians,
      270.toRadians,
      false,
    );

    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      size.width / 2,
      size.height * 0.70,
      leftCircleCenter.dx + arcRadius - bezierOffset,
      leftCircleCenter.dy + arcRadius - bezierOffset,
    );

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

It's dynamic, the buttons are built-in. You get 2 options to work with - **onDislike()** and **onLike()** callbacks.
An example using different sizes.

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DecoratedBox(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [Color(0xffc0496f), Color(0xffdb6b59)],
          begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
          end: Alignment.centerRight,
        ),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Test'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
        ),
        body: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              for (final size in List.generate(5, (index) => index++))
                FractionallySizedBox(
                  widthFactor: 1.0 - size * 0.2,
                  child: LikeOrNot(
                    onLike: () {},
                    onDislike: () {},
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Example Image]

There's a **_gapSize** parameter which is the gap between two circles. The one you need is already inside (2% default) but you can get some cool other variations by changing it. For example, here's a gap of 20% total width:

[image]

Comment: wow!!!!. you just save me.i have been working on this for 2days now. Thank so much.